# Find the area bound by two intersecting circles and a tangent line to one of the circles

Tags: geometry, circles, area, tangent-line

There is a circle with radius r1 and centre D

This intersects a circle with radius r2 and centre C

Tangent line AB is always tangential to circle with centre D

It can be assumed the circle with centre C is free to move, and can be both inside and outside of circle D, with centre C also being able to be either side of the tangent line - I will update with edited images and scenarios (an all encompassing is the dream haha!)

Updated query - Is there a way to find the area bound shaded green/yellow? I have been around the houses subtracting sectors and am struggling to find my mistakes, to the point I believe my apporach may well be (is!) off, so I'm not looking to lead anyone!

```
UPDATE - That said, hold the phone, can we get there by adding green (just intersecting circles equation), and yellow as being:
```

Yellow = [Area_tri BPA] - [Area_Segment BDP] + [Area_Segment ACP]

I updated the image to better reflect all scenarios of where circle C can be in relation to the tangent line and circle D

I'll clean this query all up once we resolve so it is less cluttered!

I have code which currently can move circle C so that it intersects only the tangent line (area cut from C = segment)
and also for when it is only the circles C&D intersecting (area cut from C = circles intersection) and when no intersection with tangent or circle D, (area cut from C = 0)

[image: UPDATED - Image describing the required area in green/yellow combined]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Where is point $B$ with respect to the $CD$ line? If you move $B$, the area between $AB$ and $P$ will change.

Comment: Angles $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ are connected with distance $d$ by sine and cosine rule, so there is only one independent value of three. But this value is not sufficient to find area, because you need to add angle $CDB$. For specific location of $C$ shown in picture green area is sum of sector $ACQ$ (I suppose $A$ is on circle with center $C$), triangles $ACB$, $BCQ$ and circular segment $BDQ$.

Comment: Interesting, I will try this out tomorrow (I'm in the UK time zone!) From what you say @IvanKaznacheyeu - presumably that calculation changes only if C is to the left of the tangent? Or do you anticipate being above line BD to be differing scenarios as well?

Comment: @Andrei - It can be assumed that C can move and area changes, so I was looking toward a generic formula, although it looks like there may be differing scenarios based on C being in/out of circle D && left/right of the tangent line? Currently my code on my project copes well with if: - Circle with centre C "only" interacts with the tangent line (just a segment) - Only C and D interact (intersecting circles) - Nothing interacts (area = 0) - So it's only this case I believe that is left for when they all interact

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu - I attempted your method by measuring in AutoCAD the different summations and clarified A to be on the circle C perimeter. Currently that method gets quite close to the area, but it looks like an very accurate approximation, I'm getting around a 5% error summing the triangles, segment and sector as you mention

Comment: @Acetonic My formula for summation is correct only for first and last drawings in picture. What are input parameters for calculating area? I suppose there are 4 independent parameters: $r_1$, $r_2$, $d=CD$ and $\angle CDB$ (angle value is positive when $AC$ does not cross line $BD$ and negative when $AC$ crosses line $BD$).

Answer (score 1):

Let the point $D$ of your diagram be the origin of the coordinate system and define the center of the smaller circle at point $C$ $(x_C,y_C)$.  We then have the equations for the two circles (when $y_C < 0$),
$$
y=\pm \sqrt{r_1^2 -x^2}\\
y=\pm \sqrt{r_2^2 -(x+x_C)^2}-y_C
$$
To find the intersection of the two circles, points $P$ and $Q$, equate the above equations to determine $(x_P,y_P)$ and $(x_Q,y_Q)$.  Doing the algebra we find,
$$
x_P = -x_C (\frac{ x_C^2 + r_1^2 - r_2^2}{x_C^2 + y_C^2}) + \sqrt{x_C^2 (\frac{ x_C^2 + r_1^2 - r_2^2}{x_C^2 + y_C^2})^2-\frac{[(x_C^2 - y_C^2 + r_1^2 - r_2^2)^2 + 4y_C^2 (x_C^2 - y_C^2)]}{x_C^2 + y_C^2}}\\
y_P=\sqrt{r_1^2 - x_P^2}\\
x_Q = -x_C (\frac{ x_C^2 + r_1^2 - r_2^2}{x_C^2 + y_C^2}) - \sqrt{x_C^2 (\frac{ x_C^2 + r_1^2 - r_2^2}{x_C^2 + y_C^2})^2-\frac{[(x_C^2 - y_C^2 + r_1^2 - r_2^2)^2 + 4y_C^2 (x_C^2 - y_C^2)]}{x_C^2 + y_C^2}}\\
y_Q=-\sqrt{r_1^2 - x_Q^2}
$$

[image]

Denote the line segment $PQ$ by $L$
$$
L^2=(x_P - x_Q)^2 + (y_P - y_Q)^2
$$
and from the opposite angle formula of trigonometry,
$$
L^2= 2r_1^2 - 2r_1^2\cos(\theta_1)\\
\cos(\theta_1)=1-\frac{L^2}{2r_1^2}
$$
The area of the isosceles triangle in the big circle is
$$
\frac{1}{2}Lh\\
h=r_1\cos(\frac{\theta_1}{2})\\
\cos(\frac{\theta_1}{2})=\sqrt{\frac{\cos(\theta_1)+1}{2}}=\sqrt{1-\frac{L^2}{4r_1^2}}\\
\frac{1}{2}Lh=\frac{1}{2}Lr_1 \sqrt{1-\frac{L^2}{4r_1^2}}
$$
The area of the piece of the pie subtended in the big circle by $\theta_1$ is $\frac{1}{2}r_1^2 \theta_1$, therefore the area of overlap below the line segment $L$ is
$$
\frac{1}{2}r_1^2\cos^{-1}(1-\frac{L^2}{2r_1^2})-\frac{1}{2}Lr_1 \sqrt{1-\frac{L^2}{4r_1^2}}
$$
In like manner we find the area of overlap above the line segment $L$,
$$
\frac{1}{2}r_2^2\cos^{-1}(1-\frac{L^2}{2r_2^2})-\frac{1}{2}Lr_2 \sqrt{1-\frac{L^2}{4r_2^2}}
$$
and thus the area of the overlap of the two circles (green region in you diagram) is
$$
\frac{1}{2}[r_2^2\cos^{-1}( 1-\frac{L^2}{2r_2^2})+r_1^2\cos^{-1}(1-\frac{L^2}{2r_1^2})-L(r_2 \sqrt{1-\frac{L^2}{4r_2^2}} + r_1 \sqrt{1-\frac{L^2}{4r_1^2}})]
$$
The area in the region

[image]

of your diagram is
$$
\int_{x_B=-r_1}^{x_P} (\sqrt{r_2^2 -(x+x_C)^2}-y_C)dx-\int_{x_B=-r_1}^{x_P} (\sqrt{r_1^2 -x^2})dx\\
=\frac{1}{2}(x_C + x_P)\sqrt{r_2^2 - (x_C + x_P)^2}-\frac{1}{2}(x_C - r_1)\sqrt{r_2^2 - (x_C + r_1)^2}\\
-y_C (x_P + r_1)\\
 - \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{r_1^2 - x_P^2} + \frac{1}{2}r_2^2\tan^{-1}(\frac{x_C + x_P}{\sqrt{r_2^2 - (x_C + x_P)^2}})\\
-\frac{1}{2}r_2^2\tan^{-1}(\frac{x_C - r_1}{\sqrt{r_2^2 - (x_C - r_1)^2}}) + \frac{1}{2}r_1^2\tan^{-1}(\frac{x_P}{\sqrt{r_1^2-x_P^2}}) + \frac{r_1^2\pi}{4}
$$